# making Openwrt stop because of svn issue

Tags: svn, proxy, openwrt

I am in the make process of the OpenWrt for an embedded system. in the middle of the make process, I get the following error:

Checking out files from the svn repository...
svn: Write error: Broken pipe
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS request for 'http://opkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'

But I know what is the problem. The dear Google dose not support our country IPs and I can just use proxy(such as your Your Freedom) to access the site.
but I don't know how to use Your Freedom in the Linux terminal. or any solution to fix the problem.
thanks to all for taking precious time

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2015? Please, upvote and accept if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Just to make sure that you know: Google Code is closing soon. Get your project outta there. For example, moving to Sourceforge would be a good option (their support is really helpful with the migration) or to a self-hosted solution.*

The error that you get indicates lack of access permissions or invalid password. Make sure that the username-password is correct. Otherwise, I suggest contacting Google support. If it actually exists, however I doubt about that. It seems that Google does not support its "free" products.

You've specified [proxy](/questions/tagged/proxy) as one of the tags. If you need to configure a proxy for your Subversion client, then read [SVNBook | Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts). The options you are interested in are:

- `http-proxy-host`
- `http-proxy-password`
- `http-proxy-port`
- `http-proxy-username`

  etc

Comment: thank you for your reply. I can see and download codes from Google Code by proxy(your freedom) in browser. but in the terminal when compiling the kernel, I do not know how to access proxy.

Comment: @user3397145 you should configure those options, i.e. `http-proxy-host` etc.